# Display the total of the SUM (price * quantity) from SELECT query

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with my products quantity and price.
I would like the total amount of all the products together.

In a data back I have a column with prices and a column with quantity

I would like to add all the values together and display them
Just as an example I have 2 products

```
a £15 quantity 4
b £20 quantity 5
```

The output should be £160

Please note that I have a lot more products in the actual DB this is just an small example to show you what the aim is

I tried the following:

```
$query_getTotal = "SELECT SUM(price * Quantity) as Total FROM Stock";
$getTotal= $conn->prepare($query_getTotal) or die(errorInfo());
$getTotal->execute();
$Total = $getTotal->fetch();

<?php echo $Total; ?>
```

The output here is ARRAY

Any help on how to achieve that would be great.

Comment: Could you provide the exact output you get from the echo? You should get an array which includes an index of the result you're looking for.

Comment: You need to look for fetch column

Comment: @Skully is actually prints ARRAY on the screen, is there a way to display it better?

Comment: My mistake, I should have clarified you should use `var_dump($Total)`, this will show display the contents of the array.

Comment: Most likely `$Total['Total']` as you already have an alias on the column (or  `$Total[0]` if only numerically indexed columns)

Comment: @NigelRen that was the solution thanks